# MVC Mapping between View Model and Request-Response messaging pattern

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, automapper, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have the following MVC design pattern issue and confused which way to go.

In the UI layer, a View Model is used in a Controller action method. Cool.

The Service layer uses the Request-Response message pattern, so the service class method has a Request object as a parameter (in), and the method returns a Response object (out). This method calls a Repository method with a Domain object parameter. In other words, to call the service method, you need to populate the Request object with your data, and the method returns results in the Response object, i.e. request-response messaging.

To pass your data in your View Model to the Domain object in the Service method, you have two options AFAIK:

1. Ensure the Request object contains the same properties as the View Model properties, then you can map (manually or automatically) values from the View Model to the Request object.
2. The Request object contains a property of the View Model, i.e. instance of the View Model now lives in the Request object (different from above option - only one property). Now you can simply assign the View Model to the property in the Request object.

I see flaws in either approach...

In option 1, if the View Model has many properties, and you are using a mapper (e.g. AutoMapper), in the Controller method you need to automap  the properties from the View Model to the Request object. Then in the Service layer, in the service method you need to automap the properties in the Request object to the Domain object. Two levels of mapping - very wrong!

In option 2, the Request object contains a property containing the View Model. You can then automap the Request.vm (property) to the Domain object easily and efficiently, but this for some reason look like poor design to me! I'm concerned about this design.

**Which is the best approach? Or is there another better approach to mapping between VM and R-R pattern?**

Comment: This is why I prefer Entity Framework because it allows me to create models.  I use strong types for everything and thus don't have the problem of Auto Mapping.  For your situation perhaps option 2 is the best as it follows the "Favor composition over inheritance" principal.  That is, your Request object "contains" the vm properties you need.

Comment: @JohnPeters I'm using EF, domain model pattern, and the repository pattern. Can you please explain how you use strong types in the UI layer instead of view models? (If I've understood you correctly). Thanks.

Comment: +1 for nicely explained valid question. It probably would have been a bit more easier to understand if you would have added some code sample (very simple).

Comment: @SBirthare Thanks :) Yeah I normally put code in the question, but was in a rush to get the question out today.

Comment: @ThomasVeil I use EF Poco classes throughout the entire design.  It's all about the data, and the data is very easily modeled into POCO classes that are understood even at the SQL layer.  The ViewModel simply kicks off the proper queries based on the response from the user on what they want to do.  This leaves the controller almost devoid of any logic other than to submit the POST.  This is why all my VMs have a method named Post.  The Post method doesn't need any parms. passed in because the selected values are bound to the property and are already there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request/Response is a *messaging* pattern, but it appears you are not using messages.. instead you are using objects.  This is the real crux of your problem.  You're using the pattern incorrectly, and more importantly, it seems like you're using the wrong pattern for the job.  Why do you need messaging in this instance?  It's just extra overhead for a simple multi-layer application.

If you really want to use messaging, you should probably serialize the data to json or xml, pass that to your service, then deserialize the data into whatever object you are using in that layer.  In this way, you don't need any dependency on the data types of the other layer, because the (de)serialization process does not necessarily require such dependencies.

Personally, I would avoid the whole messaging aspect and have a mapping layer that maps between your view model and your domain object, then call your service layer with the domain object.

Answer (score 1):

I live without Request object in the scenario you described above.

I just use domain object (POCO classes/entity) from Service layer -> Presentation layer.

While preparing a response from the controller, I convert Domain object returned from service layer into ViewModel object using AutoMapper.

With above approach, as you can see, the option 1 is no more a problem at all. Domain to VM and vice versa configuration is done once and there you go.

When a web request comes in, it has a ViewModel object that converted back to Domain model before being passed to service layer.

I am not sure if you can consider it as "another" or "better" pattern. If the idea sounds good to you I can provide more information if required.